# Can i create and delete entity in core data by coding

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I want to create and delete entity in core data by coding(no gui-Swift3), is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can create entities at run time as well as instances, although it's very unusual and has a couple of potential problems to be aware of.

First, you can create instances of `NSEntityDescription` to create a new entity. Use instances of `NSAttributeDescription` and `NSRelationshipDescription` to complete the new entity. Add the new entity to a managed object model by modifying the `entities` property on your `NSManagedObjectModel`.

Things you need to know before attempting this:

1. The model can't be modified after you have loaded a persistent store file. So you must do the above **before** attempting to access any data with the model. Models are read/write until you load data but read only afterward. Modifying the model after loading data will cause your app to crash.
2. You must create the **same** entity every time you use it with a persistent store file-- unless you perform model migration to reflect the new entity description.
3. You can't use `NSPersistentContainer`, because it hides too many of the details. You'll have to use the older (but still supported) approach where you write your own code to load the model and then use `addPersistentStore(ofType:configurationName:at:options:)` to load your persistent store file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and delete **records** of an entity, but not the entity itself.

The model cannot be changed at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't create/delete entity because model will not be changed run time..You can **Create** / **Update** / **Delete** / **Select** records from entity.

Answer (score 0):

Three functions to save or delete objects in coredata:

-(BOOL)deleteObjectFromDB:(NSManagedObject *)object eSalva:(BOOL)andSave {

```
if (!object) {

    NSLog(@"DB Error");
    return NO;

}

[_managedObjectContext deleteObject:object];

if (andSave)
    return [self saveDB];

return YES;
```

}

-(BOOL)saveDB {

```
BOOL result;
result = [_managedObjectContext save:nil];

if (!result)
    NSLog(@"DB Error: database saving error");

return result;
```

}

deleting all objects

-(void) deleteAllObjects: (NSString *) entityDescription  {

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityDescription inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *error;
NSArray *items = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
[fetchRequest release];


for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in items) {
    [_managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
    DLog(@"%@ object deleted",entityDescription);
}
if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    DLog(@"Error deleting %@ - error:%@",entityDescription,error);
}
```

}

Returning to your question:

[here there is a way to delete entities](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/wiki)

hope it helps.